# User's to create content and save on server

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a Asp.Net Web APP, and I'm trying to figure out how I can allow users to create content and save it on a large file system in my Computer

My thought process being something like this:

1. User john113 creates a project: projectA
2. If the directory on the remote machine /serverstore/john113 does not exist, create it.
3. If the directory on the remote machine /serverstore/john113/projectA does not exist, create it.
4. john113 creates itemA in projectA and saves the item, I write the file to /serverstore/john113/projectA/itemA

How can I access this remote server , which is a windows machine, and be able to do the actions I've listed above.

Will I need some instance of Windows Server running on this remote machine, with open file permissions?

Comment: If the target file system is available over a network connection, you can write to it like you would any file system.  If not, you would need some kind of protocol for writing files (such as FTP).  Before worrying about how to do it *in code*, first determine how you would do it *manually*.  If you're logged in to the web server that will host this web application, how from that server can you write to the target file system?  Once you have that, doing it in code is easy.

Comment: @David Ah so if I'm deploying to Azure, I would have to configure the Web.config in someway and supply it a destination to write all files?